# How to show model's value in JList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I have a ArrayList and I feel it with models,I want to show models value in Jlist,I pass arraylist to Jlist and convert it to array but I don't know how to display the value of each object.
my code is here:

```
ListIterator<PhoneModel> listIterator = list.listIterator();

while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
    PhoneModel value = listIterator.next();
    System.out.println("The phone number of "+value.name+" is "+value.number);
}
jList.setListData(list.toArray());
```

thanks for any help my friends!

Comment: Use a [*Custom Cell Renderer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override toString() method on `PhoneModel`, so it automatically displays it as label in JList.

Comment: tnx very much,is it possible for you to explain more about toString() please?what does exactly this function do?(sorry about my enlish)

Comment: the `toString()` method returns a string representation of the object. When the Object is a String, then it returns its value. if no toString method is defined then `Object.toString()` is called which returns a literal string representing the type of object. 
It's important to override the method if you use the model bean in statements like `System.out.print(phoneModel)` or in your case, because under the hoods java calls phoneModel.toString() to print its string representation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DefaultListModel` to get data from iterator. then create new `defaultlistmodel` runtime and add this `model.addElement(yourvariable.ToString());`

For Eg. here it takes Listarray..

```
DefaultListModel<String> model;

private void UpdateJList()
{
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(Person p : personList){
     model.addElement(p.ToString());
}    
clientJList.setModel(model);     
clientJList.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

}

model data insert into jList..